# MySQL check if file exists on the server

Tags: mysql, file-exists

I am developing an application using PHP, MySQL. I have a table in my mysql database which has got file names stored in it. I want to trigger 'SELECT' query which will check (from the file names in table) if file exists on the server. If yes, it should return yes, else no. I tried using LOAD_FILE but with no success. Please let me know how can i do this using MySQL's SELECT query.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason for having to do this in MySQL and not PHP?

PHP has a function called file_exists http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php that is perfect for this. Your MySQL server should not have access to your whole file system, so I suggest that you do this with PHP if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use inotifywait on a file. Load it with LOAD_FILE and trigger a PHP/batch script?